# j_security_check connection interrupted

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat

I am using tomcat's authentication. When I leave the login page open for about half an hour so and then try to login, I get the following error:

URL: `http://localhost/pc/j_security_check`

Page Content:

Connection Interrupted

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

The network link was interrupted while negotiating a connection. Please try again.

- My guess is that since tomcat uses jsession cookie to maintain session and it times out, I get this error. What would be a good solution to this problem ?
  I am using Tomcat 6.0.20

Comment: Curious why the connection to j_security_check - which is the default URL for handling login attempts - would time out. Even if it does care if you have an active session, it should just redirect you or handle this gracefully. What versions of Spring and Spring Security are you using?

Comment: using spring 2.5.6 and not using spring security. using tomcat 6.0.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just let the login page refresh itself whenever the session times out. You can make use of the meta refresh header and [`HttpSession#getMaxInactiveInterval()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getMaxInactiveInterval%28%29) here. The last  returns the amount of seconds the `HttpSession` has yet to live and that's exactly what you need in a meta refresh header.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="${pageContext.session.maxInactiveInterval}">
```

Include it in the HTML `<head>` of your login page.

Answer (score 0):

Good NEWS! It is now fixed in Tomcat from version 7.0.5 and newer -> https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3839.

So your another solution may be to switch to a newer Tomcat (of course it may not be so easy).