# refresh a <ui:composition when j_security_check connection interrupted (http 408)

Tags: session, authentication, jsf-2, primefaces, j-security-check

I have a **"j_security_check connection interrupted (http code 408)"** and proposed solution is `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval}"/>` by https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141274/1852036 but my page structure is a *composition* using a *template.xhtml* and a *view.xhtml* like a `<ui:composition`: 
**my template.xhtml:**

```
<html ...
<f:view ...
<h:body ...
 <ui:insert name="content">
...
```

**my view.xhtml to refresh when *session.maxInactiveInterval***

```
<ui:composition ...
<ui:define name="content">
...
```

may anyone help me to do this? I want to refresh this `<ui:composition` view, I can't use `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval}"/>` on ***template.xhtml*** because it's used by several views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used p:poll for a similar problem. Something like

```
<p:poll interval="#{session.maxInactiveInterval - 1}" process="@all"/>
```

Comment: what does process="@all" means?

Comment: @all to process the whole page

Comment: I always set the interval with -1 because I've met the problem that the session did timeout before the refresh was done and it was not acting as expected.

Comment: My bad. It should be inside the }. Updated now.